# Equivalence of conditions for the restricted sum of a finite family of stable subgroups of a group with operators (Bourbaki)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product, quotient-group

I am having difficulty following the proof of the following proposition proved by Bourbaki in his Algebra book:

> *Let $G$ be a group with operators in $\Omega$ and $(H_{i})_{i\in I}$ a
>   finite family of stable subgroups of $G$. For $G$ to be the restricted
>   sum of the family of subgroups $(H_{i})$, it is necessary and
>   sufficient that each $H_{i}$ be normal and that $G$ be the product of
>   the quotient groups $(G/H^{i})$, where $H^{i}$ is the subgroup
>   generated by the $H_{j}$ for $j\neq i$.*
>
> **Proof**. The condition is obviously necessary. Conversely, suppose $G$
>   is the product of the $K_{i} = G/H^{i}$ and let let $G$ be identified
>   with the product of the $K_{i}$. Then $H_{i}$ is identified with a
>   subgroup of $K_{i}$, so that, for $j\neq i$, every element of $H_{i}$
>   is permutable with every element of $H_{j}$; on the other hand,
>   $H^{i}$ is identified with the product of the $K_{j}$ for $j\neq i$,
>   hence $H_{i}=K_{i}$ for all $i$ and $G$ is the direct product of the
>   $H_{i}$.
>
> (Algebra, Chapter 1, $\S \ 4$, no. $9$)

First of all, I cannot see why the condition is "obviously" necessary. For each $i\in I$, let

$$\iota_{i}:H_{i}\rightarrow \bigoplus H_{j}$$

be the injective homomorphism such that $\iota_{i}(x)(i)=x$ and $\iota_{i}(x)(j)=e$ for all $j\neq i$. Letting $incl_{i}$ denote the canonical injection of $H_{i}$ into $G$, we have $\Phi\circ\iota_{i}=incl_{i}$ by definition, where

$$\Phi: \bigoplus H_{i}\rightarrow G,\ (x_{i})\mapsto \Pi x_{i}$$

is the isomorphism whose existence we have assumed. Since $\iota_{i}(H_{i})\vartriangleleft \prod H_{i}$ and $\Phi$ is a homomorphism, we have $H_{i}\vartriangleleft G$ for every $i\in I$. Therefore, $(H_{i})_{i\in I}$
is a family of normal subgroups of G; whence, $\bigvee_{j\neq i} H_{j}=H^{i}\vartriangleleft G$ for each $i\in I$.

Ok, so far so good.

Now, I am not sure how to prove that

$$\Psi: G\rightarrow \prod G/H^{i},\ g\mapsto(p_{i}(g))_{i\in I}$$

is a bijection.

On the other hand, I also cannot follow Bourbaki's proof of the sufficiency of this condition: specifically, I am not sure how to construct the following identification

$$H^{i}\simeq \prod_{j\neq i} G/H^{j}.$$

I know that if $I$ is finite, we have $\bigvee \iota_{i}(H_{i})=\prod H_{i}$; hence,
$$H^{i}=\bigvee_{j\neq i} \iota_{j}(H_{j})=\prod_{j\neq i} H_{j}\simeq\{x\in\prod H_{j}\ |\ x_{i}=e\},$$
and similarly we have
$$H_{i}\simeq(\prod H_{j})\ / \{x\in\prod H_{j}\ |\ x_{i}=e\}.$$

But can these properties be used to prove the result?—I have no idea how to utilise the quotient groups $G/H^{i}$; it seems to me that this might be what's causing me so much trouble—but I am not sure.

I would appreciate any hints.

Some definitions from Bourbaki:

> 1) Let $G$ be a group with operators in $\Omega$ and $(H_{i})_{i\in I}$ a family of stable subgroups of $G$. $G$ is called the **internal
>   restricted sum** (or **restricted sum**) of the family of the
>   subgroups $(H_{i})$ if every element of $H_{i}$ is permutable with
>   every element of $H_{j}$ for $j\neq i$ and the unique homomorphism of
>   $\bigoplus H_{i}$ into G whose restriction to each of the $H_{i}$ is the
>   canonical injection is an isomorphism.
>
> 2) Let $G$ be a group with operators in $\Omega$ and $(H_{i})_{i\in I}$ a family of normal stable subgroups of $G$. Let
>   $p_{i}:G\rightarrow G/H_{i}$ be the canonical homomorphism. G is
>   called the **internal product** (or **product**) of the family of
>   quotient groups $(G/H_{i})$ if the homomorphism $g\mapsto(p_{i}(g))_{i\in I}$ is an isomorphism of G onto $\prod G/H_{i}$.

Comment: You don't quote correctly Definition 1: the symbol is not $\prod H_i$ but something looking like a rectangle, which is sometimes denoted $\bigoplus H_i$ (denoting the restricted sum, in Bourbaki's terminology, and more commonly as restricted direct product). Anyway this doesn't matter in this proof since the index set is finite.

Comment: Anyway I'm not prone in going into these technicalities, it looks like much effort to prove something which is somewhat trivial. A categorical point of view is much more intuitive to understand these things, and unfortunately Bourbaki made another choice.

Comment: You're right: the symbol appearing in the french version of the book is something different. I'm not sure why the english version contains the product symbol. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: The English version has the same symbol for the product and restricted sum?

Comment: Yes. You can see it here, on page 47: https://books.google.ca/books?id=STS9aZ6F204C&printsec=frontcover&dq=bourbaki+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv8orOv-flAhUCm-AKHecEACwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=restricted%20sum&f=false

Comment: It's clearly a typo from the English translation. The original symbol (symmetrized version of $\prod$) is not standard, and the translater didn't notice that it differs from $\prod$.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what happened.